# Access the oracle database on local network from ec2 instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, database-connection

I am not able to access the Oracle database hosted on local server from the EC2 instance.

Code (Run on databricks with AWS):

```
empDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//hostname:1521/SID") \
    .option("dbtable", "hr.emp") \
    .option("user", "db_user_name") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .load()
```

But I am not able to connect to the server.
Error: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-12170: Cannot connect. TCP connect timeout of 15000ms for host 100.x.x.x port 1521

Changes done in the security group:
Added outbound and inbound rules:
Custom-TCP---Port-1521---Destination- Custom(100.x.x.12/32)

Changes done in the VPC network acls settings:
Added outbound and inbound rules:
Custom-TCP---Port-1521---Destination- Custom(100.x.x.12/32)

Please let me know if any other setting has to be done in the AWS/Databricks